# Firefox ignores font-size on pseudoelement

Tags: firefox, webkit, font-size

Regarding this pen: http://codepen.io/sjchmiela/pen/bfLrF

In Webkit it looks ok, in Firefox the text is smaller.

http://f.cl.ly/items/28293C0M2x2p430O3P37/Zrzut%20ekranu%202013-06-15%20o%2019.02.03.png

What to do to make Firefox obey the `font-size` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font-size seems to be working fine (you can set it to 90px and see it change).

Chances are, the two browsers are just using different fonts.  If neither Helvetica nor the default sans-serif font have a glyph for that Unicode character (which seems likely for this character), the browser will fall back to some font that *does*, and which one is somewhat random.

The right way to deal with this is to specify a font family that actually has the character.

Comment: I think that's the reason, I'll search for the right font, when I find it I'll post it here. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up just using webfonts from [fontello](http://fontello.com). Support isn't that bad http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface and there is really no way to find the font used by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding !important next to the font size like this:

```
font-size: 45px !important ;
```

Hope it helps!